# React Native: Element Type is invalid Exspecting a String

Tags: react-native

```
    import {CITYIMG} from '../assets/index';

    export default class Login extends Component {


    render() {

    return (
      <Container>

        <Image source = {CITYIMG}/>

        <Card style={styles.card}>
          <Text>
            Sign In
          </Text>

          <Item rounded>
            <Input placeholder='Username'/>
          </Item>

          <Item rounded>
            <Input placeholder='Password'/>
          </Item>

          <Button hasText transparent>
              <Text>Forgot Password</Text>
            </Button>

            <Button rounded>
            <Text>Login</Text>
          </Button>

          <Button rounded>
            <Text>Sign Up</Text>
          </Button>

        </Card>
       
      </Container>
    );


    }


    }
```

I am exporting images in another folder and get the error:

> Expected  String or a class function but got undefined . You likely forgot to export your component from the file its defined in.

```
export const CITYIMG = require('./cityimg.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for having static images you need to have `source={require("../Path/To/picture.extention")}`

**and you need to require them when you want to use it in the same file(not by exporting and importing)**

Comment: I believe thats what I have

Comment: you should call your require function in the same file. that is the trick!

Comment: if you want the logic behind it I can explain you .

Comment: please do!! @em.d

Comment: can you share your code via GitHub? I will help you in advance